# Installation of a python package available locally is failing

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have flask package both in tar ball format and .whl format  . Installation using pip command fails . Below commands demonstrate the failure

```
[root@localhost ~]# pwd
    /root
    [root@localhost ~]# ls -l | grep -i flask
    -rw-r--r--  1 root   root    91364 May 28 06:56 Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    -rw-r--r--  1 root   root   644534 May 30 03:44 Flask-1.0.2.tar.gz
    [root@localhost ~]#


    [root@localhost ~]# pip install --no-index --find-links=file:////root Flask-1.0.2.tar.gz
    Looking in links: file:////root/
    Processing ./Flask-1.0.2.tar.gz
    Collecting Werkzeug>=0.14 (from Flask==1.0.2)
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Werkzeug>=0.14 (from Flask==1.0.2) (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for Werkzeug>=0.14 (from Flask==1.0.2)
    [root@localhost ~]#

    [root@localhost ~]# pip install --no-index --find-links=file:////root Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Looking in links: file:////root/
    Processing ./Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24 (from Flask==1.0.2)
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement itsdangerous>=0.24 (from Flask==1.0.2) (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for itsdangerous>=0.24 (from Flask==1.0.2)
```

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas on fixing this

Comment: From what I understand from documentation, options `pip install --no-index --find-links=...` mean `do not use package index` and `only look for package locally`. As `Werkzeug` and `itsdangerous` are not available locally, but required, `pip install` fails. If you wish to install Flask, simply write `pip install Flask`. I would suggest to do it inside a python environment though (e.g. `python -m venv myvenv` then `source myvenv/bin/activate` then only `pip install ...`

Comment: @zezollo. thank you .